# Nested list mapping using MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

How can I do the bean mapping using MapStruct for the below scenario.

```
class Source {
private String sourceId;
private List<Course> courses;  //always returns only one course
}

class Course {
private String courseName;
private List<Student> students; 
}

class Student {
private String studentName;
}

class Target {
private String targetId;
private String subjectName;
private List<Member> members;
}

class Member {
private String memberName;
}
```

Now I want to map sourceId to targetId, courseName to subjectName, studentName to memberName(list to list).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all is `Source` contains always one course why not make it a `Course` element instead of a `List`?

If you do that the mapping would be much simpler. With your current setup it is a bit more complex.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "targetId", source = "sourceId")
    @Mapping(target = "subjectName", source = "courses")
    @Mapping(target = "members", source = "courses")
    Target map(Source source);

    default String subjectName(List<Course> courses) {
        if (courses == null || courses.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return courses.get(0).getCourseName();
    }

    default List<Member> toMembersFromCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        if (courses == null || courses.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return toMembers(courses.get(0).getStudents());
    }

    List<Member> toMembers(List<Student> students);

    @Mapping(target = "memberName", source = "studentName")
    Member toMember(Student student);
}
```

If `Course` is not a list. then you can do it more elegant with 1.2.0.Final.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "targetId", source = "sourceId")
    @Mapping(target = "subjectName", source = "course.courseName")
    @Mapping(target = "members", source = "course.students")
    Target map(Source source);

    @Mapping(target = "memberName", source = "studentName")
    Member toMember(Student student);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Why Course is list ? That's the requirement. Also can you update the answer with the correct source code for the mapper class. Returned Member list instead of Student list for the first toMembers() method.

Comment: I don't think I follow. The source code returns a `List<Member>`

Comment: I am getting compile time errors with  the above code.

Comment: You are right it had compile errors. But not because it was returning `List<Member>`. It was because both of the `toMembers` method had the same erasure. I renamed the first `toMembers` into `toMembersFromCourses` and now it compiles and generates the correct code. If you change the first one to return `List<Student>` MapStruct will generate an internal method and won't use the one defined from you

Comment: Thanks, now I got the required output.